# Лимит на количество открытых дескрипторов

Tags: linux, файлы, golang

Пишу демон на go, используя [go-daemon](http://github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon). Вопрос вот в чем:

Какой лимит, по умолчанию, на количество открытых дескрипторов файла в go? Как его менять? И есть ли общепринятые  рекомендации по их количеству?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Начать стоит с проверки `ulimit -a` и `ulimit -aH` в shell'е *перед* запуском вашего демона. Это быстро покажет текущие "мягкие" и (второй вызов) "жесткие" ограничения. При помощи `ulimit` можно открутить мягкие ограничения до пределов жестких. Следует понимать, что `ulimit` меняет только текущие лимиты, для шелла и всех программ, запущенных в этом шелле, поэтому после завершения сессии или даже в другом окне терминала значения останутся прежними.
2. Следующее место задания ограничений, на этот раз постоянных — это `/etc/security/limits.conf` и каталог `/etc/security/limits.d/`, ограничение называется `nofile`. Редактировать (а, иногда, и смотреть) эти файлы может только суперпользователь ("root"). Там задаются ограничения на отдельных пользователей или группы, применяемые на всю сессию данного пользователя, или всех пользователей определенной группы.
3. И наконец, есть "системное ограничение", задаваемое через sysctl - это `fs.nr_open`:

   /sbin/sysctl -n fs.nr_open

ему же соответствует файл `/proc/sys/fs/nr_open`

"Программно" манипулирование лимитами текущего процесса в пределах жестких ограничений, заданных на сессию, осуществляется через вызовы [getrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getrlimit)/[setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setrlimit), которые можно звать из Go, используя FFI (см. примеры, н-р, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740315/how-do-i-call-c-from-go-using-the-foreign-function-interface))